# Error Message with fileinfo verification

Tags: php, validation, fileinfo

I am getting error message using the below infofile script to verify if the uploaded files are pdf and send via phpmailer.

Line 66 is where the "default:" at. If I delete default the next line become error and so on. Not sure what is wrong with the script.  Can someone please help. thx.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'default' (T_DEFAULT) in
>   /test.php on line 66

```
if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
die("Upload failed" . $_FILES['upload']['error']);
}
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$ok = false;
switch($mime) {
case 'application/pdf'
default:
   die("not permitted file type");
 $ok = true;
    foreach($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] as $uploadfile) 
    $mail->AddAttachment($uploadfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the colon after your first (non-default) `case`. Should be:

```
switch($mime) {
case 'application/pdf':
//                    ^
default:
```

Additionally: I'm not sure what do you want to happen in the first case, but if that's the allowed case you should also use `break` before the `default` case. Otherwise the interpreter will execute it too (or any other cases after it).